# Assign multiple tables to single class in linq table mapping

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I may be asking the question wrongly as I'm getting to grips with Linq. I have searched for a solution and the only thing I have come up with is the possibility that inheritance is the answer, but I cannot work out how to use it in this case. I am using c# and have created a class for a table as:

```
[Table(Name = "CommonDocumentData1800")]
public class CommonDocumentRecordData
{
    [Column]
    public string RecordID;
    [Column]
    public int? StartYear;
    [Column]
    public int? EndYear;
    [Column]
    ....
}
```

I have multiple tables (e.g. CommonDocumentData1800, CommonDocumentData1900, CommonDocumentData2000), but I want to use the same class rather than repeating the class with a different name. How do I deal with this?

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with `LINQ`.

Comment: all the tables have same fields?

Comment: Bit unfair to down vote. I said I was getting to grips with Linq and I would have thought it a legitimate question. Even if it is nothing to do with Linq, I would still appreciate a way of resolving the problem.

Comment: absolutely specially without giving a reason. upvoted

Comment: Sounds more like entries than tables

Comment: Mark, would you mind explaining?

Comment: After 9 years, I have the same question here... Try to find a way to solve this problem, but still in vain.

Answer (score 0):

You can include multiple enumerables in a linq query. In order to populate your `CommonDocumentRecordData` object you could do this:

```
var allTables = (from t1800 in  CommonDocumentData1800.AsEnumerable()
                 select new CommonDocumentRecordData
                {
                 RecordID = t1800.Field<string>("RecordId"),
                 StartYear = t1800.Field<int>("StartYear"),
                 EndYear = t1800.Field<int>("EndYear")
                }).Union(
                from t1900 in  CommonDocumentData1900
                //and so on
                );
```

Comment: How do you map the `CommonDocumentData1900` to some class in the model? This works ONLY if you define many classes of the same structure such as `CommonDocumentData1800`, `CommonDocumentData1900`, ... and that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem. It sounds like these are logically segmented tables with identical schema. Probably the cleanest way to handle this is with a view in the database. Then if you create your model on the view object, there's no need for any of this. If you're using an Entity Data Model, it will make all of these classes for you, and I guess if you have no control over the underlying data model, you would WANT some additional logic for splicing it. --To answer your claim: same schema is not necessary - since you can customize property assignment in your query.

Comment: @KingKing: I believe this is what you might have been after: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2007/03/15/inheritance-in-the-entity-framework.aspx In Entity Data Model, you can define `TableMappingFragment` to handle cases such as this.